# smbiosview - command not found

Tags: bios, rhel7

I have RHEL 7.5 installed. I am trying to get the pci cards info using "smbiosview" command. But it is saying "command not found"

```
[root@myhost ~]# smbiosview -t 202
bash: smbiosview: command not found...
```

I have tried "dmidecode command", but it doesn't contain complete information

```
[root@myhost ~]# dmidecode -t 202
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2.1 present.
# SMBIOS implementations newer than version 3.1.1 are not
# fully supported by this version of dmidecode.
```

How to get it working? Do I need to install any packages

Answer (score 1):

dmidecode should give you everything you need as the SMBIOS table and the DMI table are essentially the same thing.  What information is not provided by dmidecode?

Using dmidecode, you can dump the raw SMBIOS table to a file and decode it yourself using:

```
$ sudo dmidecode --dump-bin dmi.bin
```

This will give you the raw SMBIOS structures, something like this (the first 64B of my SMBIOS table):

```
00000000   5F 53 4D 5F  BF 1F 02 05  BD 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  _SM_............
00000010   5F 44 4D 49  5F FE CB 0B  20 00 00 00  4F 00 25 00  _DMI_... ...O.%.
00000020   00 18 00 00  01 02 00 F0  03 1F 90 DE  8B 7F 01 00  ................
00000030   00 00 33 05  08 0F FF FF  41 6D 65 72  69 63 61 6E  ..3.....American
00000040   20 4D 65 67  61 74 72 65  6E 64 73 20  49 6E 63 2E   Megatrends Inc.
```

At offset 0x0, you see _SM_, the SMBIOS anchor string, and at offset 0x10 you will find _DMI_, the DMI anchor string, also aligned to 16-byte boundary to support legacy search tools.  This will be followed by the raw data in the SMBIOS table. You can decode this table using the SMBIOS spec, found [here (SMBIOS Reference Specification, version 3.2.0](https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.2.0.pdf)